# want to convert SQL query to LINQ query in E.F

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am developing app with MVC 3.5 and EF.

I have written the SQL query and I want to rewrite in the LINQ, but I don't know how to use it...

here is the sql query

```
select * from PurchaseOrders where CreatedById in
(select Employees_Id from EmployeeRole where Roles_Id in 
(select Roles_Id from EmployeeRole where Employees_Id = 17))
```

[image]

Comment: Need your schema. Honestly do not get what you are trying to do in WHERE clause.

Comment: It looks like a strange kind of join...

Comment: Please check now... I have added the Model Diagram...

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33900/LINQ-FAQ-for-Newbie-s good starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:-

1. your context is set up correctly and you have all the navigation
   properties in place
2. your query is "Get me all of the purcahse orders
   created by any employee who shares a role with employee #17"

You can use:-

```
context.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == 17)
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Roles)
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Employees)
                 .Distinct()
                 .SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseOrders);
```

Comment: Nice one. But shouldn't you add a `Distinct()` after SelectMany Employees?

Comment: Depends on the behaviour the OP wants, but yeah that sounds most reasonable.

Comment: You are genius Iain, I have the same req. but i dont get the x . what is it ?

Comment: @user1650894 Is Iain's assumption #2 correct? (This is how i read your sql query, too)

Comment: yes it is...2nd assumption is right...but its now working , giving syntax error ...

Comment: No... SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseOrders); its not right...cant find Purchase orders...

Comment: What's the navigation property on the Employee end of the Employee/PurchaseOrder relationship called?

Comment: Sorry lain, It was my mistake, I forgot the relation, one one issue remains earlier I have written the query as            // `ViewBag.PurchaseOrderIdList = new SelectList(new List<PurchaseOrder>(), "Id", "PONo");` now I want to use your query , how to use it ?

Comment: Just pass it in as the first parameter to the constructor of the SelectList.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your above query is just a bit weird and you actually meant to do:

```
SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE CreatedById = 17;
```

Your LINQ query would be:

```
PurchaseOrders.Where(Order => Order.CreatedById = 17);
```

or

```
var Orders = from Order in PurchaseOrders
             where Order.CreatedById = 17
             select Order;
```

Seeing your update I guess you would actually be better off selecting you employee and then all of the purchase orders i.e.

```
var Orders = Employees.Single(x => x.Id == 17).PurchaseOrders;
```

but beware above will work only if there is such an employee

Comment: Why are you involving 3 tables? You only have one parameter and you are not trying to get either user role or the user...

Comment: Get me all of the purcahse orders created by any employee who shares a role with employee #17

Answer (score 0):

```
var s= (from po in _db.PurchaseOrders
                join er in _db.EmployeeRoles on po.CreatedById equals er.Employees_Id
                let _ser in _db.EmployeeRoles.Where(c=>c.Employees_Id == 17)
                where  _ser.Select(c=>c.Roles_Id).contails(er.Roles_Id)
        Select po).toList();
```